# How do I test whether core data migration is working using adhoc builds?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have configured my app to use migration e.g.:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
```

What I want to do now is create an ad hoc build and test it on my devices.

Usually I would delete the app from iTunes and delete the app on my device and then drop the new build into iTunes and then sync to copy over the new build to my device.

But in order to test the migration I want the old db to stay on the device.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way of updating ad hoc builds is by using a third party tool called TestFlight.  It allows you to monitor crash reports and installations of builds and remotely and you don't need iTunes.  It's great because each use of your app just updates the app instead of deleting it each time.

[How do I release updates to adhoc builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819925/how-to-i-release-updates-to-adhoc-builds)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple - once you know where to look.# In your AppDelegate you set-up the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator - and you need to add some options to this to tell it to handle auto-migrate:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,

[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

NSError *error;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];

if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType        configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
      // Handle error
    NSLog(@"Problem with PersistentStoreCoordinator: %@",error);
}
```

Then you need to do in xCode:

1. Select your xcdatamodeld file
2. Select the Editor Menu at the top - then choose Add Model Version
3. Now your xcdatamodeld file have two (modelname.xcdatamodel & modelname2.xcdatamodel ) .
4. Now modelname.xcdatamodel  have the green check mark implies it is current version, but we need to change the modelname2.xcdatamodel as a current version
5. Select the xcdatamodeld file and then select the View Menu at the top - then Choose Utilities - then Choose the Show File Inspector is shown in right side of Xcode and then Select the Versioned Core Data Model - have Current(DropDownList) - select modelname2(the one you just made current version have green check mark).
6. Now when you install this version onto a device that has the old model - it will automatically upgrade that model to the new model.

keep all of the changed files and then once you get ready to deploy your update you'll delete all the in-between files and just deploy with the oldest and latest models. vice versa (step 4,5,6) for latest to old model(current)

Comment: As my question states, how do I install an ad hoc build over an existing app on the device without deleting the app from the device

Comment: your two build must be ad hoc first install old one(before your actual change) with [Bundle versions string, short] in plist and update new one with [Bundle versions string, short] greater than old one.

Answer (score 1):

don't delete the app from iTunes and the app on your device and then over right  the new build into iTunes and then sync to copy over the new build to your device. always keep [Bundle versions string, short] greater for new one now its just update the old one with new one. Already I done it with Testflight.