# How do I release updates to adhoc builds?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I want to release an update to my ad hoc build that exists on my various devices?

UPDATE:  I don't mind doing it manually for each device my question is, how do I update the app's without deleting them first off the device.  i.e. I want to keep the database on the device in tact...itunes doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you will have to install a new build on every device via iTunes.

Or you can try [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/), it's a great tool. And you can just install a new builds from the device itself. And if you include TestFlight SDK you will be able to get all the sessions and all the crashes of that app(with stacktrace).

Update: use [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/). You don't have to delete the app in order to install a newer one. I use Core Data and NSUserDefaults and after installing a newer build nothing is being lost. So I guess it's something you are looking for.

Comment: You rock!  TestFlight is awesome.  Is it totally free?

Comment: @TheLearner I'm glad that you liked it :) According to their About page( https://testflightapp.com/about/ ) it is "A Free web service for mobile developers, project managers, and app testers."

Comment: Weird but I am not complaining!

Answer (score 1):

I f you use OTA to distribute your ipas than I think, you can just update those file on your server and  if the bundleid and product name haven’t changed, and the bundle version and the CFBundleVersion short numbers are higher than the ones that are deployed, its should update the deployed apps. (I am not 100% sure about it though)...